# xdebug code coverage analysis with simpletest framework

Tags: xdebug, simpletest

I am doing unit testing with simpletest framework and using xdebug for code coverage reports. let me explain you my problem:

- I have a class which I want to test lets assume name of class is pagination.php.
- I write another class for testing. I wrote two test cases to test pagination class.
- there are around 12 assertion in two test cases which giving me correct result "Pass".
- Now I want to generate code coverage report, for this I use xdebug to show that my test cases covering all code or not. I use xdebug_start_code_coverage() function and for showing result I use xdebug_get_code_coverage() function.

Now the problem is that, when I print xdebug_get_code_coverage() Its give me 2 dimension assosiative array with filename, line no and execution times. the result is like this:

```
array
  'path/to/file/pagination.php' => 
    array
      11 => int 1
      113 => int 1
```

line 11 is start of class and line 113 is end of class. I don't know why it is not going inside class and why it is not giving the statement coverage for class functions. However, my test cases looks ok to me and I know all condition and branching covering are working.

I will really appreciate if you help me in this regard and guide me how to solve this problem.

Maybe I missed something here. If you want something more please let me know.

Comment: No body there to answer my question. Please let me know if question is unclear or not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an XDebug-CC for a class with invoked methods and it works fine. Though I have to say that I am a bit confused about how this tool defines "executable code", it definitely takes account of methods.

You might check the location of your xdebug_start_code_coverage() and xdebug_get_code_coverage(), as those have to be invoked at the very beginning and the very end.

Also you might check your XDebug-version, as there has been some accuracy-improvements since the feature has been released.

Best

Raffael

Answer (score 0):

SimpleTest has a coverage extension that is fairly easy to setup. IIRC it is only in svn and not the normal packaged downloads. (normally in simpletest/extensions/coverage/)

You can see articles for examples of how to implement it:

http://www.acquia.com/blog/calculating-test-coverage
http://drupal.org/node/1208382